# Intermittent browserify bundle failure (probably brfs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

This is an intermittent problem. That is, I can repeat the same build command n times without changing anything and sometimes it will work and sometimes (~30%) it will fail with seemingly no cause. I've been living with this for months now, but it is terribly annoying.

I'm using node (v0.10.35) and browserify (v6.3.4) and brfs (v1.2.0) to bundle some html in my javascript. Intermittently, the build fails with:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
SyntaxError: Unterminated string constant (17:4) while parsing file: blah.js
    at raise (./node_modules/brfs/node_modules/static-module/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:333:15)
    at readString (./node_modules/brfs/node_modules/static-module/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:1073:11)
    at getTokenFromCode (./node_modules/brfs/node_modules/static-module/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:854:14)
    at readToken (./httpd/node_modules/brfs/node_modules/static-module/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:902:15)
    at next (./node_modules/brfs/node_modules/static-module/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:1232:5)
    at eat (./node_modules/brfs/node_modules/static-module/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:1335:7)
    at expect (./node_modules/brfs/node_modules/static-module/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:1360:5)
    at parseExprList (./node_modules/brfs/node_modules/static-module/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:2443:9)
    at parseSubscripts (./node_modules/brfs/node_modules/static-module/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:2032:24)
    at parseSubscripts (./node_modules/brfs/node_modules/static-module/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:2021:14)
    at parseExprSubscripts (./node_modules/brfs/node_modules/static-module/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:2012:12)
    at parseMaybeUnary (./node_modules/brfs/node_modules/static-module/node_modules/falafel/node_modules/acorn/acorn.js:1995:16)
```

It's different line numbers, but each time the build fails, it points to

```
fs.readFileSync(
```

I don't think it matters, but I am using gulp v3.8.8. My gulp task is quite simple.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
  return browserify(app.src, {
    fullPaths: true,
    transform: ['brfs'],
    debug: true
  }).bundle().pipe(source(app.name)).pipe(gulp.dest(app.dest));
});
```

Others on this same project with slightly different versions of node and gulp and even different OSes are also experiencing the same problem.

Update: It also fails with just browserify+brfs (most current versions) with the same message. I'm convinced this is a problem with brfs because it doesn't seem to fail if I leave out the transform.

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var fs = require('fs');
var b = browserify('blah.js');
b.transform('brfs');
b.bundle().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.js'));
```

Comment: Does it fail in the same fashion if you just make the browserify API calls without gulp in the picture? What about if you remove the `transform` opt you're passing and instead do `).transform(require('brfs')).bundle(`? Any chance you could try updating the browserify version?

Comment: Thanks @JMM for the suggestions. I tried .transform(...), but it still randomly fails, but it does seem to be about 20% faster using that, so thanks for that. I haven't tried your other suggestion yet.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to try to rule out a race condition when browserify has to resolve the transform module from the string name.

Comment: just tried it without gulp, just node and browserify+brfs, still fails randomly

Comment: Can you post an example of one of the offending `readFileSync` lines with some surrounding lines for context? Would it be possible to create an example that reproduces for you with a handful (or ideally 1) bundled file(s) (the simpler and more minimal the better)?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this problem with a similar setup (using reactify to transform, though; it was just giving me "Unterminated string constant" in the error message and didn't specify a js file). Turned out I had a syntax error in a json file (a stray newline inside of a string literal)...

Comment: Thanks so much! I had a corrupted json files as well.